# Attemping to add a value to a HashSet doesn't change the amount of values in it

Tags: c#, hashset

I have a `HashSet` and when I use the `Add` method of the collection, nothing is added. The output  is still `2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13` and the output from `.Count` is 6.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

```
namespace AllerDiz
{
    class MainClass
        {
            public static void Main (string[] args)
            {
                HashSet<int> smallPrimeNumbers = new HashSet<int> { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 };
                smallPrimeNumbers.Add (3);
                smallPrimeNumbers.Add (5);
                smallPrimeNumbers.Add (7);
                Console.WriteLine ("{0}", smallPrimeNumbers.Count);
                foreach(int val in smallPrimeNumbers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("HashSet Value= {0}", val);
                }
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: I see there is research done while posting the question. It is better to learn the basics first.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. This is precisely how a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is supposed to work.

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.

So, if the item you are trying to add already exists in the set, the set is not modified.

If you want a collection which does allow duplicates, look at [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

From [`HashSet<T> Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The HashSet class provides high-performance set operations. A set
>   is a collection **that contains no duplicate elements**, and whose
>   elements are in no particular order.

From [`HashSet<T>.Add Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Return Value true if the element is added to the HashSet object;
>   **false if the element is already present.**

`HashSet` is a kind of optimized collection. Its constructor eliminates the non-unique elements.

For example;

```
string[] array = new string[] {"one", "one", "two", "two", "three", "three"};
HashSet<string> hash = new HashSet<string>(array);
string[] array2 = hash.ToArray();
```

`array2` will be `{"one", "two", "three"}`

If you want to add duplicate values, [`List<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection allows you to add duplicate values.

Answer (score 3):

One of the main features of HashSet is ensuring there are no duplicates